# SMP Control Manager detected SMP is not responding to HTTP requests. The http status code and text is 500, Internal Server Error

Tags: iis, configuration-management, sccm, sccm-2007

I am getting this error in one of the Management Point.

SMP Control Manager detected SMP is not responding to HTTP requests.  The http status code and text is 500, Internal Server Error.

All Application Pool in IIS is working fine.

There is no error in Eventvwr-system and Application.

For SMS State Migration Point Pool -ADVANCED SETTING - Enable 32bit Application mode=False

[image]

All worker Process running in 64bit mode

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to be sure the SMP has been successfully installed and configured. (Has it even worked before? Review smpMSI.log and SMPMgr.log)

Some other factors will cause this. Things like incorrect permissions on the folder specified in the State Migration Point properties, or the folder specified does not exist anymore. So I suggest below:

1. Review log file SMPMSI.log, SMPMgr.log and MPControl.log
2. Be sure the folder specified in SMP component properties is still valid.
3. Be sure the permission on the folder is set correctly.

Comment: Thank you FrankDong for your help

Answer (score 1):

I located the folder SMSSMP_VIRTUAL and given Full control security setting to local service which solved the issue.

[please find screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5FUm.png)